# How can I add Tailwind to ejected CRA app and get it to compile?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css, create-react-app

We ejected create-react-app and want to add TailwindCSS to our project. However it doesn't seem to be compiling or adding the styling to our elements. When I run the build command, the resulting css file doesn't have any tailwind styling in it.

I ran `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./dist/tailwind.css --watch` and that did compile a css file in a new dist folder.

Because of our other dependencies, we are using Tailwind v2.

```js
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: [
      "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "./src/**/*.html"
    ]
  },
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

```css
// index.css
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

...
```

```
// index.tsx
import "./index.css";
import App from "./app/App";

...
```

webpack.config.js is not changed from ejecting

I think these are the relevant dependencies:

```json
"postcss": "7.0.39",
"postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.2.1",
"postcss-import": "15.1.0",
"postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
"postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
"postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
"postcss-safe-parser": "5.0.2",
"react": "17.0.2",
"webpack": "4.44.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.11.1",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
"tailwindcss": "2.2.19"
```

Update: After adding a few console logs, the output from `getStyleLoaders` in webpack.config.js is:

```js
// "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
// "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
// "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
// In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
// to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
// of CSS.
// By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
  use: [
  {
    loader: '/path/to/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js',
    options: {}
  },
  {
    loader: '/path/to/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js',
    options: { importLoaders: 1, sourceMap: true }
  },
  {
    loader: '/path/to/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js',
    options: { 
      ident: 'postcss', 
      plugins: () => [
        require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
        require('postcss-preset-env')({
          autoprefixer: {
            flexbox: 'no-2009',
          },
          stage: 3,
        }),
        // Adds PostCSS Normalize as the reset css with default options,
        // so that it honors browserslist config in package.json
        // which in turn let's users customize the target behavior as per their needs.
        postcssNormalize(),
      ], 
      sourceMap: true 
    }
  }
],
  // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
  // containing package claims to have no side effects.
  // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
  // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
  sideEffects: true,
},
```

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app - can you try  `@tailwind base;`  instead of `import`

Comment: @the.marolie Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately that didn't work. I'm following this guide - https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#include-tailwind-in-your-css. But either way, still nothing.

Comment: Okay, one more thing - you need to include `post-css` loader in webpack.
`{
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
    },`

Comment: Just updated the question. I logged what the output is from webpack. It looks like the CRA team has that in place :/

Comment: what happens when you add tailwind utility classes to your elements? Any change at all ?

Comment: No, nothing at all. I've been testing by adding a "tailwind" button, and also by trying to build the project

Comment: @ChristopherR. First thing I'll say is that moving to Vite solved everything! But.. my client decided to not use Vite. I'll post the webpack config as the answer. We went through about 5 iterations with different issues, so I'm not sure what fixed this particular problem. Sorry!

Comment: @snowkid314 Thank you, anything you could provide I'm sure would be a huge help!

Comment: @ChristopherR. That is posted. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally got this working. I don't remember which iteration fixed this particular issue since we faced quite a few problems. So I'll post the important pieces of the webpack, tailwind, and storybook configs here.

webpack.config.js

```
// common function to get style loaders
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        // css is located in `static/css`, use '../../' to locate index.html folder
        // in production `paths.publicUrlOrPath` can be a relative path
        options: paths.publicUrlOrPath.startsWith('.')
          ? { publicPath: '../../' }
          : {},
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: cssOptions,
      },
      {
        // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
        // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
        // package.json
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
          // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
          // ident: 'postcss',
          postcssOptions: {
            plugins: () => [
              require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
              require('postcss-preset-env')({
                autoprefixer: {
                  flexbox: 'no-2009',
                },
                stage: 3,
              }),
              // Adds PostCSS Normalize as the reset css with default options,
              // so that it honors browserslist config in package.json
              // which in turn let's users customize the target behavior as per their needs.
              postcssNormalize(),
            ],
          },
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment,
        },
      },
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
      loaders.push(
        {
          loader: require.resolve('resolve-url-loader'),
          options: {
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment,
            root: paths.appSrc,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
          },
        }
      );
    }
    return loaders;
  };

  return {
    resolve: {
      // This allows you to set a fallback for where webpack should look for modules.
      // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
      // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
      modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
        modules.additionalModulePaths || []
      ),
      // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
      // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
      // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/290
      // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
      // for React Native Web.
      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
        .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
      alias: {
        // Support React Native Web
        // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
        'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        // Allows for better profiling with ReactDevTools
        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
          'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling',
          'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
        }),
        ...(modules.webpackAliases || {}),
      },
      plugins: [
        // Adds support for installing with Plug'n'Play, leading to faster installs and adding
        // guards against forgotten dependencies and such.
        PnpWebpackPlugin,
        // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
        // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
        // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
        // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
        // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
        new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [
          paths.appPackageJson,
          reactRefreshOverlayEntry,
        ]),
      ],
    },
    resolveLoader: {
      plugins: [
        // Also related to Plug'n'Play, but this time it tells webpack to load its loaders
        // from the current package.
        PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module),
      ],
    },
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },
        {
          // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
          // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
          // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
          oneOf: [
            // TODO: Merge this config once `image/avif` is in the mime-db
            // https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db
            {
              test: [/\.avif$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                mimetype: 'image/avif',
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
            // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
            // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'),
                    {
                      runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? 'automatic' : 'classic',
                    },
                  ],
                ],
                
                plugins: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                    {
                      loaderMap: {
                        svg: {
                          ReactComponent:
                            '@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref![path]',
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                  isEnvDevelopment &&
                    shouldUseReactRefresh &&
                    require.resolve('react-refresh/babel'),
                ].filter(Boolean),
                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                compact: isEnvProduction,
              },
            },
            // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
            // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true },
                  ],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                
                // Babel sourcemaps are needed for debugging into node_modules
                // code.  Without the options below, debuggers like VSCode
                // show incorrect code and set breakpoints on the wrong lines.
                sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
                inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
              },
            },
            // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
            // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
            // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
            // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
            // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
            // of CSS.
            // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                  ? shouldUseSourceMap
                  : isEnvDevelopment,
              }),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
            // using the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                  ? shouldUseSourceMap
                  : isEnvDevelopment,
                modules: {
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
              }),
            },
            // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
            // By default we support SASS Modules with the
            // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
            // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                  modules: {
                    getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                  },
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
            },
            // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
            // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
            // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
            // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
            // that fall through the other loaders.
            {
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpacks internal loaders.
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
            // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  purge: { purge: true, content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"]},
...
}
```

storybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
    "@storybook/addon-storyshots",
    "@storybook/addon-storyshots-puppeteer",
    "@storybook/jest",
    "@storybook/testing-library"
  ],
  features: {
    interactionsDebugger: true
  },
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  core: {
    "disableTelemetry": true,
  },
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.devtool = 'eval-source-map'
    return config;
  },
}
```

FYI - with this config, icons are not rendered in Storybook stories. I recommend moving to Vite and Storybook 7.

react-app-env.d.ts

```
/// <reference types="node" />
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference
/// <reference types="react" />
/// <reference types="react-dom" />

declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface ProcessEnv {
    readonly NODE_ENV: "development" | "production" | "test";
    readonly PUBLIC_URL: string;
  }
}

declare module "*.avif" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module "*.bmp" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module "*.gif" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module "*.jpg" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module "*.jpeg" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module "*.png" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module "*.webp" {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module "*.svg" {
  import * as React from "react";

  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string }>;

  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module "*.module.css" {
  const classes: { readonly [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}

declare module "*.module.scss" {
  const classes: { readonly [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}

declare module "*.module.sass" {
  const classes: { readonly [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
```